# Is there a way to encrypt or hide JSON or header info in http calls/requests

Tags: http, vue.js, flask, axios

So I am working on a full stack website using Flask, Vuejs and SQLite3. I am using axios to call the backend from the front end. I noticed though that if I 'GET' request information from axios(Vuejs) to the backend on a route, that all that information can be seen in plain text (JSON) on that route. I tried requiring a 'secret' from the header which does work, but the header information can be viewed in plain text as well, and it shows the 'secret'. I tried socket.io as well but those socket.io requests can be viewed in plain text as well.

Is there a way to encrypt or hide 'GET' requests but still allowing that information to get to the frontend from the backend on any IP that calls my site?

So for example say I have a database with a column and value of: Header1: 500. On the frontend I want to show that 500 in the HTML. So using axios I use a .get(path) and call the data. In Flask I have a route with method='GET' and return the database in JSON format. On the frontend I would save the axios response in a variable and then show the variable in the HTML. And that's great and all. But the information in the 'GET' request shows 'Header1: 500' in plain text. Now obviously that's not a big deal with that not very important value. But say I am calling an entire database to the frontend to display parts of it or use the values; those values are now all viewable on the Flask route to anyone.

Comment: There is no way to prevent the user from seeing requests made by the frontend.

Comment: You need to add access control to your backend.

Comment: Yeah ... That's what I thought. But would that require users login on the site before use? Because in my case is a super small single page app that shouldn't require logins. But I understand, I will just be careful of what I pass to the front end. Thank you

Comment: If you don't require a login, there is no way to know what the user is allowed to see.

Comment: Makes sense; thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every network request can be read in plaintext, by default. There are various methods of preventing the data to be read in such way;

- login wall - assumes that the user is authorised to read the data that is sent back to him
- limiting the response - most sane way just limits the data the user is sent. Usually carries some benefit of performance gain as the responses are smaller
- encryption - you could encrypt data on backend and decrypt it in the browser, but end user would still be able to accesa front-end decryption algorithm and reverse the process

The general rule in frontend is that everything sent from the server, can be read by the user.